# How can I iterate through map entries for a single key value? Maps with a value of type list

Tags: apex, map

I have a map which has more then one entry for each key value, how can I iterate through just those records for a particular key value.  I don't want to do the following which iterates through the whole set, but just want to iterate through those for a particular key value, struggling to find the right syntax - probably missing something straightforward!

```
Map<id,List<ERP_Customer__c>> acctErpMap = new Map<id,List<ERP_Customer__c>>();

// code to put values in map to go here ... 

for (id key : acctErpMap.keyset())  
{  
    System.debug(logginglevel.INFO, 'PersonAccount DEBUG: MAP key = ' + key);  
    System.debug(logginglevel.INFO, 'PersonAccount DEBUG: MAP value = ' + acctErpMap.get(key));         
}
```

Following the help given by those who responded to the call I re-coded as per following:
1. A map of lists has been created.
2. The id of the map has therefore been able to be kept unique
3. The code now posted below shows:
(a) Setting up and populating the map.
(b) Reading back through the map.

```
/*****************************************************************
    Note: ERP_Customer__c is a child of the Account object.
    Create a map, acctErpMap, of lists as follows:
******************************************************************/ 
Map<id,List<ERP_Customer__c>> acctErpMap = new Map<id,List<ERP_Customer__c>>();
// Create an empty ERP list for each account record. 
For (Account acc : accList) 
{ 
    acctErpMap.put(acc.id, new List<ERP_Customer__c>());
}

//    Populate ERP_Customer__c list for each account being processed                 
for (ERP_Customer__c ERPChild : ERPFullList)
{
    acctErpMap.get(ERPChild.PersonAccount__c).add(ERPChild);
}

// Loop through accounts.
For (Account acc : accList)
{ 
    // Logic removed for purpose of post.
    // ...

    // Loop through ERP_Customer__c for this Account
    for (ERP_Customer__c ERPChild : acctErpMap.get(acc.id))
    {      
        // Logic removed for purpose of post...
        // ...
    }               
}
```

Comment: Do you know that particular key which you need? Will that always be constant?

Comment: Yes I do know the key I need.  Essentially I have an outer loop (looping around a list), each iteration of this loop provides me with a key which I want to use to access records in the map.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but are you looking for something like
`for(value val : acctErpMap.get(key).values()){
//do logic
}`
What type of Map is it? Is it a `Map<Id,List<SObject>>`?

Comment: I've posted an answer which might help, but without an [edit] to your question, which includes the type of the map, as @ToddSprinkel mentions, we won't be able to help you much further.

Comment: Yes the map I think does need to be Map<Id,List<SObject>> - as I've now included in code snippet.  In which case I guess I would then have unique values as keys to the map.  So then I probably need the for loop mentioned by you @ToddSprinkel to access the data.  I guess the other part of the puzzle was populating a map with a list.

Comment: Hopefully I can work out what to do now - will let you know how I do and respond appropriately later...  Thanks

Comment: If an answer has helped you, click on the check next to the upvote/downvote arrows to mark it as the accepted answer, so others know this question is solved. If you run into other issues, [ask](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question with a reference to this one so others are aware of the starting point for the question.

Comment: Ok, progressed - and added some code above as to what I've now done, having trouble with a syntax error when attempting to see of a particular id already exists in the map (using contains).

Comment: @RichardPenwell I've added an edit to my answer with the proper method to use. If you have any further questions, I'd recommend asking a new question over making more edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one value per key in a map. Calling `Map.put(...)` on the same key will replace the existing value in the given key.

Try running the snippet below in a developer console to display this behavior.

```
Map<String, Boolean> mapAndValues = new Map<String, Boolean>();

// Assign multiple values to same key 
mapAndValues.put('test', true);
mapAndValues.put('test', false);

System.debug(mapAndValues.get('test')); // will return false
```

An alternative option to using `put` on the same key would be to use a list type as the value to the map.

```
Map<String, List<Boolean>> mapAndValues = new Map<String, List<Boolean>>();

// Assign empty list  
mapAndValues.put('test', new List<Boolean>());

// Modify list reference from get 
mapAndValues.get('test').add(true);
mapAndValues.get('test').add(false);

System.debug(mapAndValues.get('test')); // will return (true, false)
```

To iterate over the records in your list as specified in your question, you'll need to create a loop which acts on the list provided from calling `get` on the key.

```
// First log id to be used to get other records 
System.debug(logginglevel.INFO, 'PersonAccount DEBUG: MAP key = ' + id);  

// Loop over list at specified key 
for (ERP_Customer__c erp:acctErpMap.get(id))  
{  
    // Log each record 
    System.debug(logginglevel.INFO, 'PersonAccount DEBUG: MAP value = ' + erp.Id);         
}
```

---

To check if a key is in a map, you need to use the method [`containsKey(...)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_containsKey), as opposed to the method `contains`.

```
someMap.containsKey(someKey); // returns either true or false
```

Comment: Whilst I was helped by comments (rather than an answer) asking me for further information given by @ToddSprinkel, this answer was also useful in my working out what to do.  As this is the only actual answer I will mark it up as solving the issue, but in fact both did - thanks...

Comment: Guess I'll have to open another one for the syntax error - a bit new to this, but cannot work it out!!

Comment: If you're having trouble getting adjusted, I'd recommend taking a day or two to try the [Apex Developer Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trail/force_com_dev_beginner). It might help.

Comment: Figured it out and posted my final code now - I don't disagree with your suggestion regarding Trailhead though!  Thanks.

Comment: Lifesaver. Great common sense answer to how to make a list from the map.